# LabelingFunction won't show all the labels

Tags: plotting, labeling

I am trying to plot a `ListPlot` where each point has a label. Unfortunately Mathematica seems to decide that is a label is too large, it will not show it. I would very much like all the labels to be shown! Any help would be much appreciated.

MWE:

```
ListPlot[{1, 1, 0.75, 0.75, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2} ->
    {a1, a2, 2 b1 + b2, b2, c1, c2 + c3 - c1, c3 - c2 + c1, c4,d1, d2, d3, d4}]
```

[image: Not all points are shown]

Notice that the points that should be labeled `c2 + c3 - c1` and `c3 - c2 + c1` are missing their label. I know that if I set `ImageSize->Large` these will show, but I want to use this within a manipulate environment whereby the number of points will change and don't want to set a huge plot when it may only contain a small number of points, and if the number of points gets larger then `ImageSize->Full` may not be good enough.

Comment: While acknowledging that this does not answer your question; note that for those points for which the label is suppressed, the label is converted to a `Tooltip` which can be seen when the mouse is over the point.

Answer (score 4):

I am uncertain how large your labels may grow. To me it seems impossible to print many large labels on a small figure.
I can only offer answers obtained by trial and error and by "jittering" points:

- just putting the labels between quotation marks shows the labels literally and helps somewhat (figure 1);
- "jittering" (adding a negligible amount of 'noise' to the values) helps a lot (figure 2).

I wonder wether this solution works within your manipulate environment. May be it is also possible to use a smaller font.

```
ListPlot[{1, 1, 0.75, 0.75, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
   0.2} -> {"a1", "a2", "2 b1+b2", "b2", "c1", "c2+c3-c1", "c3-c2+c1",
    "c4", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"}]
```

[image]

Now I add 0.000001 to the 11th value and make its label even longer.

```
ListPlot[{1, 1, 0.75, 0.75, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.200001, 
   0.2} -> {"a1", "a2", "2 b1+b2", "b2", "c1", "c2+c3-c1", "c3-c2+c1",
    "c4", "d1", "d2", "d3+q1+w3+z6+h7", "d4"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Does mapping `TraditionalForm` or `StandardForm` on the labels work?

Answer (score 3):

If the number of points is not "too large":  `Plot` with the option `ImageSize -> Full` and use the result in `Show` with desired `ImageSize`:

```
Show[ListPlot[{1, 1, 0.75, 0.75, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2,  0.2} ->
       {a1, a2, 2 b1 + b2, b2, c1, c2 + c3 - c1, c3 - c2 + c1, c4,  d1, d2, d3, d4}, 
   ImageSize -> Full], 
  ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Some labels are still suppressed if the number points is too large:

```
data = RandomInteger[100, {200, 2}];
labels = RandomWord["Noun", 200];
Show[ListPlot[data -> labels, ImageSize -> Full], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]